# MYSQL - Show all rows including nulls

Tags: mysql

There are two tables I am working with.

**ft_form_1**
ID | facility_id | admits | discharges | census | pending | reporting_date | last_modified_date

**ft_field_options**
ID | option_value | option_name | option_order | list_id

With the below query, I am able to get a list of all 'submissions' from today from all facilities with a list_id equal to 1. If duplicate submissions are sent, only the most recent submission will be shown.

**Question:** This query only shows a list of facilities that have submitted today and their subsequent data sent. How do I also show the list of facilities that have not submitted today and display blank or null values?

```
SELECT t1.facility_id, t2.option_name, t2.option_order, t1.admits, 
t1.reporting_date, t1.last_modified_date, t1.discharges, t1.census, 
t1.pending, DATE_FORMAT(t1.reporting_date,'%m/%d/%Y') AS nicedate
FROM ft_form_1 t1
LEFT JOIN ft_field_options t2
ON (t1.facility_id = t2.option_value AND t2.list_id = 1)
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(t1.reporting_date,'%m/%d/%Y') = 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y')) AND (t1.last_modified_date=(
SELECT MAX(last_modified_date)
FROM ft_form_1
WHERE facility_id = t1.facility_id))
ORDER BY option_order ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

your  qusation is so simple just follow your selection and you cand find your answer by test and  run in many times without any more knowalage about mysql

```
SELECT t1.facility_id, t2.option_name, t2.option_order, t1.admits, 
t1.reporting_date, t1.last_modified_date, t1.discharges, t1.census, 
t1.pending, DATE_FORMAT(t1.reporting_date,'%m/%d/%Y') AS nicedate
FROM ft_form_1 t1
LEFT JOIN ft_field_options t2
ON (t1.facility_id = t2.option_value AND t2.list_id = 1)
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(t1.reporting_date,'%m/%d/%Y') != 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y')) AND (t1.last_modified_date=(
SELECT MAX(last_modified_date) AND (t2.optaion_name IS NULL or t2.opation_name = "")
FROM ft_form_1
WHERE facility_id = t1.facility_id))
ORDER BY option_order ASC
```

I add some things to your code , just here you are run it and add what you need more by your self